# JRuby: command pattern in Java with Ruby block: why does it work?

Tags: interface, jruby, block, command-pattern, respond-to

I am learning how to integrate Java library with Ruby code and come to the following question.

I have a command pattern implemented in Java, as follows:

```java
public interface Command {
  public String execute(String param);
}

public class CommandRunner {

  public String run(Command cmd, String param) {
    return cmd.execute(param)+" [this is added by run method]";
  }
}
```

When I import that to JRuby program I can implement Ruby class that `respond_to? :execute` with one parameter and pass it to the `CommandRunner.new.run`. That works and that's clear.

But I can also do this:

```rb
def put_through_runner(param, &block)
  CommandRunner.new.run block, param
end

p = put_through_runner "through method" do |param|
  "Cmd implementation in block, param: #{param}"
end

puts p
```

Instead of passing to Java `CommandRunner` an object implementing the `execute` method I pass it a block of code, that does not implement the method. And It works: calls the block as if it was implementation of the `execute` method! How is that possible? What does JRuby do with the block when passing it to Java? If I had the `CommandRunner` implemented in Ruby the above code would not work.

Comment: i suspect that something adds an `execute` method to your proc object. you could check that in your `put_through_runner` method.

Comment: Nothing adds the `execute` method. First: there is nothing that could do it, second: that was the first thing I checked -- in the `put_through_runner` method the `block` object does not `respond_to? :execute`.

Comment: having `respond_to?` returning `false` does not necessary mean that this is actually the case. it depends on the way `respond_to?` is implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that this works is a feature called 'closure conversion' ([see docs here](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby#closure-conversion)).  What happens is that the block you pass is converted into a `Proc` object with a proxy that invokes the code in the block for any method that is called on the object.

Comment: Great answer! I'm very grateful. I had not idea where to look for an explanation and how can I exploit this feature. Now that's clear. BTW: very nice feature of JRuby