# Pass a Ruby block to a Java method

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, block

I need my JRuby method to recieve a report of what is going on in a Java method and act accordingly:

```
def my_long_running_method
  # ... do stuff ...

  jObject.count_all_disk_files do |number_of_files|
    stream.write "#{number_of_files} files found so far."
  end

  # ... do more stuff ...
end
```

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784029/jruby-command-pattern-in-java-with-ruby-block-why-does-it-work) but I couldn't understand what I need to do.

I've known Ruby for a long time and a little of Java. This project needs to be JRuby because of old Java code that needs to be integrated with new Ruby code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a complete reference, see the [Calling Java From JRuby wiki page](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby), specifically the section about [closure conversion](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby#closure-conversion). The short answer to your question is that your Java method `count_all_disk_files` will need to accept an interface with a single method (a "functional interface"). Then JRuby will be able to automatically implement that interface with the code from the block.

Comment: this helped me a lot, even more then the official docs. thanks